# Where can I use the '??' operator?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In a JavaScript tutorial I saw someone using the `??` operator over a short circuit operator i.e. `||`

For Example:

```
const a = null;
const b = a ?? 0
```

Which essentially meant use the value of `a` and if `a` is `null` or `undefined` use a default value of 0.

But somehow in NodeJS, this results in a syntax error:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You're using Node 12, it's available in Node 14

Comment: Lemme give it a try.

Comment: Also, What is this operator called?

Comment: It's called Nullish Coalescing

Comment: [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) - I checked the table at the bottom for the Node version

Comment: Thanks you so much. Google is killing me when I search '??'. Apparently Google's just ignoring question marks in searches. Appreciate it.

Comment: See [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/4642212) and the documentation on MDN about [expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators) and [statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements). Simply Google “JavaScript double question mark operator” or something.

Comment: @deAr yeah, searching for operators is *not easy* with google. Same happens if you search for dots and similar. For these kinds of searches, you can use [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/). You can also restrict which sites it searches in. For JS, we have a canonical list that is easier to search here: [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780). You can find the link in the tag description for [[tag:javascript]] - it's almost at the bottom.

Comment: I'm loving these operators. Thank you  for letting me know these specific details guys. <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

?? **Called Nullish coalescing operator** in Javascript.

```js
const foo = null ?? 'default string';
console.log(foo);
// expected output: "default string"

const baz = 0 ?? 42;
console.log(baz);
// expected output: 0

console.log(null ?? null)
// expected output: null
```

|| this operator not return 0, false, null, "" and undefined.
**Ex. a = 0; b = 10; console.log(a || b); it return 10(b).**

If first value is NULL then it return second value.

**Note: if second value also NULL then it return null**